# Get full XML node as String with StAX

Tags: java, xml, stax

In my local environment the `startElement.toString();` returns the whole xml node as String which I can export to another xml file. But not the same behavior in the test server.

Eg: I have an input xml file with the following content:

```
 <books>
   <book isbn="125141122">Book title</book>
 </books>
```

When the cursor is on the `book` node, the `starElement.toString()` returns `<book isbn="125141122">Book title</book>` (which is the expected behavior).

But in test server (another machine), the `starElement.toString()` returns `[START_ELEMENT]Book title[END_ELEMENT]`.

```
 String filePath = "/tmp/test.xml";
 XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
 eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new FileReader(filePath));
 StringBuilder fileHeader = new StringBuilder();

 while(eventReader.hasNext()){

        XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

        if(event.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT){

            StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
            String elementName = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();

            if("book".equals(elementName)) {

                fileHeader.append(startElement.toString());
                fileHeader.append("\n");

            }
      }
 }
```

PS: Local and server java version are the same (Java1.6).

Have you any idea how to get full xml tag as string?

Comment: Weird. Might be a different way you log the `String` representation of the node? Have you tried remote debugging through a socket and inspecting the variable?

Comment: I do not have access to this server.

Comment: That doesn't bode well for figuring out anything. Maybe try replicating the server's configuration in a machine you have access to, so you can investigate.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?